# NPE when changing view visibility with radio button

Tags: android

I'm trying to change the visibility of a view and edit text by clicking a radio button, but it doesn't work.  The problem is a java null pointer.  How can I fix it?  I verified that all variables are correct.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    View rad1 = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radio1);
    View rad2 = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radio2);



    final View test = findViewById(R.id.ProvencePrefecureView);
    final EditText  test1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ProvencePrefecureEdit);
    final View test2 = findViewById(R.id.rg);
    final View  test3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Commune_arrondView);
    final EditText  test4 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Commune_arrondEdit);

    public void onRadioButtonClicked(View view)  {
        // Is the button now checked?
        boolean checked = ((RadioButton) view).isChecked();

        // Check which radio button was clicked
        switch(view.getId()) {
            case R.id.radio1:
                if (checked)
                    test.setVisibility(1);
                test1.setVisibility(1);
                test3.setVisibility(1);
                test4.setVisibility(1);
                break;
            case R.id.radio2:
                if (checked)
                    break;
        }
    }
}
```

XML:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/ProvencePrefecureView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/RegionView"
    android:layout_below="@+id/RegionEdit"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    style="@style/question"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:text="2. Province ou Préfecture : "
    />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/ProvencePrefecureEdit"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/ProvencePrefecureView"
    android:layout_below="@+id/ProvencePrefecureView"
    android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
    style="@style/reponse"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:ems="10"
    />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/Commune_arrondView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/IDENTView"
    style="@style/question"
    android:layout_below="@+id/ProvencePrefecureEdit"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:text="3. Commune/Arrondissement : "
    />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/Commune_arrondEdit"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/NumeroDiscrictEdit"
    android:layout_below="@+id/Commune_arrondView"
    android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
    style="@style/reponse"
    android:ems="10"
    />
```

Comment: post your entire error

Comment: You have to define those test, test1, test3 and test4 views final to reach them in onRadioButtonClicked method. Do yourself a favour and debug on onRadioButtonClicked method.

Comment: share your full activity code then.

Comment: That error, NullPointerException, includes a stack trace which at some point will include a reference to a particular line in your source code.  Go to that line, figure out what's `null` that shouldn't be, and fix it.  If you can't fix it, tell us exactly which line is causing the problem.

Comment: Why is all that code to set the references to your layout objects outside a method?  It will never execute.

Comment: well i didn't understand your idea, can i do it in other way ? well i appreciate your efforts and thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All code in Java must be in a method.  Try this:

```
final View rad1;
final View rad2;

final View test;
final EditText;
final View test2;
final View  test3;
final EditText  test4;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    rad1 = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radio1);
    rad2 = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radio2);

    test = findViewById(R.id.ProvencePrefecureView);
    test1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ProvencePrefecureEdit);
    test2 = findViewById(R.id.rg);
    test3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Commune_arrondView);
    test4 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Commune_arrondEdit);

}
```

Comment: i tried this one, but it didn't work ! the variables testx are not detected in the method onRadioButtonClicked(View view).

Comment: the problem happened in the the View rad1 = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radio1); but it is correct !!

Comment: Please learn about `scope`.  Declare the variables as class fields and initialise them in onCreate().  You should try some basic Java tutorials first, then learn about Android. I've edited my answer.

Comment: thanks a lot Simon, i will learn about scope as you say but first i have to finish the application i am working on it. thanks again